Metadata Indicating Scheduled Sends Vs Actual Time Sent
Is there any metadata in Microsoft Outlook emails that indicates when an email was scheduled versus when it was actually sent?
For example, if I draft an email at 3:00 PM, schedule it to send at 5:00 PM, and then press send, would any metadata or server logs reveal that the email was scheduled in advance rather than sent at the exact time it was drafted? Additionally, could an IT department access server logs to view this scheduling information?

What do you mean about "whenever someone decides to have the email be scheduled vs sent at the time you send it"?

Hi @Christy, what I mean is for example I scheduled an email to go out at 5:00 PM but I created it at 3:00 PM and pressed send. Is there any metadata or indicators that recipients can discover that would show the email was scheduled to go out at a specific time and wasn't necessarily drafted at the time it was sent.

Perhaps? Open one of these scheduled emails, open the Internet Headers and copy them, then find Microsoft's Message Header Analyzer site and paste the headers in. There will be a Creation Time value. See if that corresponds to when the email was first created/scheduled, or to when it was actually sent. You'll need to ask the given IT dept if they have that data, and we can't answer that part, but you can look at the header yourself in the MHA tool and see what that data tells you.
